# JavaFX Table Menu Button list shows text but not graphic

Tags: java, javafx, tablecolumn

I am working on an application that uses a TableView and has a Table Menu Button to add or remove columns from the list.

Since I wanted my column headers to have tooltips, I had no choice but to create a label and use it in the following manner in :

```
// Some code here
TableColumn col;
// some code here
col.setGraphic(header_title);
```

The problem with this is that when the program runs, the table menu button shows a list of empty text:

[image: Table Menu Button shows no text for the column titles]

On the other hand when I do:

```
// Some code here
TableColumn col;
// some code here
col.setText(rs.getString("column_title"));
col.setGraphic(header_title);
```

I can see the text on the column menu, but the actual titles are appended to the graphic:

[image: Column header text gets appended to graphic]

I have tried to look for a way to perform a setContentDisplay(GRAPHIC_ONLY), but this does not seem to exist for TableColumn, and I am not sure how to access the header node in order to set this setting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just forget about the inbuilt table menu button. It's absolutely minimal and not worth mentioning. If you e. g. want to click away 10 columns you have to click on the button, hide the column, click on the button, hide the column, etc. In other words: It closes as soon as you press a menu item.

You can't even extend it with e. g. a hide all and a show all button. And it's buggy: When the last column gets hidden, the menu button vanishes as well, so you have to restart your application if you want to see anything in your table again.

Just create your own table menu. There are 2 examples on this gist:

- [example which uses a lookup, i. e. works without reflection](https://gist.github.com/Roland09/d92829cdf5e5fee6fee9)
- [example which uses reflection](https://gist.github.com/Roland09/7a2701f267588a2ecf31)

Then you can adapt whatever header you want and whatever menu items you want.